# How do you get a server to upload and work for your game?

Tags: node.js, hosting

I've been searching all over the web and have attempted to upload my node.js based server up to a few various web hosters with no result. As far as I know most hosters don't support node.js to begin with, and I have a list of a few that do.

But my primary question is, how do you get your server working on this hoster in the first place? do you just upload it? does it sort of self run once uploaded? do I have to access that hosters cmd in order to get it running?

Sorry for what is probably a very newbish question, which I assume it is as I have yet to find a guide that covers this because it is apparently too basic. They always seem to skip this part:s

Comment: A VPS or dedicated would allow you to install anything you'd like, and if using Ubuntu/Debian, node.js is available as an APT package. Installation on most servers is covered in the [**Documentation**](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager)

Comment: Try AppFog (http://www.appfog.com/). It's easy to setup and deploy apps.

Comment: Thanks for the server advice and forgive the (again) newbish follow up question, but do I literally just upload my server.js file and these platforms will do the rest?

Comment: AppFog: https://docs.appfog.com/languages/node#node-walkthrough, Heroku (also free for dev level): https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs

Answer (score 0):

You'll just need to upload your files to a web host that supports javascript and offers command line access; for example, check out [Amazon's free scalable offering](http://aws.amazon.com). Once you have the files uploaded, just run them from the command line:

```
% node node.js
```

Comment: Happy to hear! :-) Be sure to click the [checkmark] to left to indicate that your question has been answered.